# Laravel 8: error when routing a GET to any view and receiving a error "Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object"

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I've created a new Laravel 8 app with Jetstream and Livewire. When I make a GET request to any view an ErrorException is launched with message

> Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object

on navigation-dropdown.blade.php which is automatically generated by Jetstream\Livewire. I've looked for this `user_id` and didn't found on any part of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Have you created users without having a personal team? The Jetstream package has some issues with it, doesn't account for much modifications to the existing views apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Check that if user has team in the blade view.

`resources/views/navigation-dropdown.blade.php`

In line 61:

```
- @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures())
+ @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures() && Auth::user()->current_team_id)
```

In line 162:

```
- @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures())
+ @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures() && Auth::user()->current_team_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortify adds it's own auth routes, but old routes in config/auth.php will still be used (in my case)

Simple solution is to comment out all routes in config/auth.php (if using jetstream with fortify)

and run :

```
php artisan route:cache
```

this will make sure that auth routes use fortify actions, so each new account you create will have team created